# Django Models com valor default em outra branch

Tags: python, django

Estou com um campo que adicionei em uma outra branch (que está com status **em desenvolvimento**) chamada `money`, com valor default: `0.00` na model `User`. Porém, ela ainda não está sendo usada na branch de produção.

Hoje quando fui fazer um teste para criar uma conta, recebi o seguinte erro:

```
IntegrityError at /users/register
(1364, "Field 'money' doesn't have a default value")
```

Percebi que em meu **MySQL** ainda está o campo `money` que havia criado em outra branch. Porém, no banco de dados ele não tem um valor default.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    ...
    money = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True, default=0.00)
```

Gostaria de entender o porque o Django não definiu como default 0.00 no MySQL. Isso está gerando um problema na criação de contas, mas não deveria pois foi criado um valor default. O Django que manualmente faz o **default value**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente, o Django configura o valor padrão por código. Acredito que o motivo disso seja porque é possível passar uma função para o valor `default`, algo que não seria viável de fazer de maneira genérica para todos os bancos de dados.

Sobre o seu problema, idealmente você deveria recriar sua base de dados ao alterar de branches, pois isso garantiria que seu banco de dados esteja de acordo com a implementação atual, isso evita muita dor de cabeça.

Comment: É complicado ficar recriando a base de dados, é uma preocupação a mais pois não é dessa forma que vou atuar em produção. Também tive problemas passando funções que geram tokens aleatórios no default. Ele entendia como um valor diferente toda vez que eu fazia migrations. Fiz o que fiz nesses casos do token, eu deixo o campo `null=True` e no save customizado eu defino um valor. Isso resolve meu problema.

Comment: Em produção você irá utilizar as `migrations`, elas servem para garantir que a estrutura de dados esteja correta, e idealmente isso seria feito por um processo automatizado de CI/CD, onde esse cenário de campo criado no banco de dados que não possui mapeamento no ORM é impossível de acontecer. Uma alternativa para evitar a destruição da base de dados local, é reverter as migrações antes de trocar de branch de desenvolvimento.